# I want to convert a dataframe into a JSON with output in a specific way

Tags: python, json, dataframe, group-by, to-json

I have a DF that looks something like this:

| studentId | startime | skill | correct | timetaken | questionid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 109670354 | Algebra | 0 | 23 | 22 |
| 2 | 109670232 | Statistics | 1 | 55 | 5679 |
| 1 | 109670111 | Algebra | 1 | 8 | 10111 |

Now I want to transform this into a JSON that would look something like this:

Note sequence can be any random number for time being

{
"Type": "XXX",
"studentId": 1,
"timestamp": "1631858259",
"data": {
"activity_data": [
{
"sequence": 1,
"question_id": 1,
"correct": 1,
"elapsed_time": 9641
},
{

```
            "sequence": 2,
            "question_id": 2,
            "correct": 0,
            "elapsed_time": 10454
        },
        {
            
            "sequence": 3,
            "question_id": 3,
            "correct": 0,
            "elapsed_time": 10454
        },
        {
            
            "sequence": 4,
            "question_id": 4,
            "correct": 0,
            "elapsed_time": 10454
        },
        {
            
            "sequence": 5,
            "question_id": 5,
            "correct": 0,
            "elapsed_time": 10454
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Note that how apart from studentId, all other columns per student fall under activity data, this is the expected outcome I'm trying to get. So essentially for each student I want to retrieve activity data, which would be the rest of the columns. I understand using a groupby function a solution could be found.

Comment: It sounds like you want to organize the data by student (studentId)? If so, I would first construct an intermediate data structure (DF) for each student, and produce the JSON from that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.